# AWS RDS: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have Postgres RDS instance which was available and working 7 days ago. Today I noticed in my app log, which is hosted in an EC2 instance that connectivity fails with

```
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres".
```

Same when I try to connect from my local machine (was just fine 1 week ago). How come my master user is not able to login anymore? What could might have happened? Is it blocked somehow, expired or stucked? What I tried so far is rebooting the RDS instance and executed the automatic RDS troubleshooting, no success. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error would only occur for one reason which is invalid authentication information. Perform the following checks:

- Check the username is correct (is postgres the username you specified when creating the RDS DB, you can validate this in the console)
- Check the password is correct

Assuming both of these values you specified you believe to be correct, you should [reset the password](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reset-master-user-password-rds/) from the RDS management console.

Regarding rotation of the password, outside of an IAM user/IAM role [modifying](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/modify-db-instance.html) the password (which could be validated via [CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/)). This could be programmatic or [via the console](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reset-master-user-password-rds/).

Can you also ensure you have not setup [password rotation via Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/rotate-amazon-rds-database-credentials-automatically-with-aws-secrets-manager/).

Comment: Nope, I dont have password rotation enabled. The username is correct, the password was correct couple of days ago either. I have no idea how come it gets invalid without any intervention from my side. How can I reset it? What else can be done?

Comment: It can be reset via the console: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reset-master-user-password-rds/

Comment: Regarding auditing validate your CloudTrail logs for RDS to see if you can see any malicious action.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me on RDS postgres as well and the only way I could get it to work was by using a [pgpass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/libpq-pgpass.html) file

Answer (score 1):

If you Copy+Paste your HOST/URL/PASSWORD from AWS secret manager make sure that there is no 'New Line' chacrcter at the end of the string (try to paste it in some text editor to be sure).

That was the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" can happen when either password is not correct, but, also when database user name is not correct. **The name of the database can be set differently from the database user name(in AWS called: *master username*)**.

So, if you have chosen a different name when creating the RDS DB in this form:[image]

..then you have to pick a proper name which you can find in RDS **Configuration** (or validate this in the console):
[image]

Many times people set the DB name as 'postgres', but sometimes they pick a different **master username** which is wise because in the future it is easier to manage a situation where you have two different db with two master usernames, one for each. In that case, the DB name should also be chosen wisely.